# Xsolla payment integration with Playfab, missing steps

Tags: javascript, c#, wpf, playfab

I'm trying to implement some payment method like Xsolla to my WPF Launcher using CloudScript function from the Revision part of PlayFab.

Right now, I can run the app and everything in the code below is executed correctly without errors.

But my goal is to be able (after the CloudScript function "xsollaPaymentToken") to go to the payment page provided by Xsolla.

Here's the code from my launcher :

```
        private static async Task<PlayFabResult<ExecuteCloudScriptResult>> XsollaCloudScriptToken()
        {
            ExecuteCloudScriptRequest executeCloudScriptRequest = new ExecuteCloudScriptRequest()
            {
                FunctionName = "xsollaPaymentToken",
                GeneratePlayStreamEvent = true,
            };
            return await PlayFabClientAPI.ExecuteCloudScriptAsync(executeCloudScriptRequest);
        }

        private async void PurchaseButtonAsync(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                await XsollaCloudScriptToken().ContinueWith
                (continuationAction: executeCloudScript =>
                {
                    ExecuteCloudScriptRequest executeCloudScriptRequest = new ExecuteCloudScriptRequest()
                    {
                        FunctionName = "xsollaGetOrder"
                    };
                }
                );
            }
            catch (System.Exception error)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(error.Message);
                MessageBox.Show(error.Message);
            }
            
        }
```

And now the CloudScript part :

[Cloudscript function screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5cDJL.png)

I think I missed some steps like redirection after the function "xsollaPaymentToken" to Xsolla interface, but since Xsolla and Playfab don't provide good docs with examples, I don't get it.

If anyone knows how to deal with those missing steps or if someone already add similar problems with Xsolla implementation, any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use PlayFab's Xsolla integration directly? It solves a lot of complexity with Xsolla such as integration with Xsolla's callback webhooks.

Answer (score 0):

maybe we can get on Discord and exchange some info.  In my case, I can  open the Xsolla paystation from the client (game or website ), purchase an item, and get a response with which Playfab grant the user an item. That works for me so if you need help let me know.

The other way is buying the item through Xsolla whithout opening paystation page with all items, but to go directly on the xsolla payement processing (with this way I have a bug)[image]

```js
};

let body =  {
    "user": {
        "id": {
            "value": "user 2"
        },
        "name": {
            "value": "John Smith"
        },
        "email": {
            "value": "john.smith@mail.com"
        }
    },
    "settings": {
        "project_id": ######
        "mode": "sandbox",
        "ui": {
            "theme": "dark"
        }
    },
    "purchase": {
        "checkout": {
            "amount": 99,
            "currency": "USD"
        }.
        "virtual items": {
            "items": [
                {
                    "gold 1999",
                    "amount": 19
                }
            ]
        }
    }
};


    // if (args.sandbox) body.settings.mode = "sandbox"

    let url= "https://api.xsolla.com/merchant/v2/merchants/" + merchantId + "/token";
    let content = JSON.stringify(body);
    let httpMethod = "post";
    let contentType = "application/json";
    let response = http.request(url, httpMethod, content, contentType, headers);
    return JSON.parse(response);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Please include code in code blocks and not as images as code in images cannot be easily copied or modified.

Comment: Great, will fix that in a bit, meanwhile, The dev I work with is going to add some comment in a bit...